# Multi line messagefield in mobileIconItemRenderer FLex

Tags: android, flash, mobile, flex4

I have a problem with my ItemRenderer in Flex. I'm developping a mobile application and I'm using a list. One of the items is to set a date. But when the date is wrong I want to set a text in my messageField like : The To date must be after the From date.

The problem is I don't know (and don't seem to find it anywhere) where you can set the messagefield in multiline. 
I read on a forum that's possible but no explanation how.

[click me to see example](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/57180376/Screen%20shot%202010-08-17%20at%205.26.39%20PM.png)

Here you can see an example of what I want (the 5the item in the list is using multiline).

I have a function in my itemrenderer to set the messagefield:

```
private function messageLabelFunction(item:Object):String
{
    var eventMessageParameter:EventMessageParameterCount = 
        EventMessageParameterCount(item);
    return eventMessageParameter.details;           
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Thibault Heylen

Comment: Please post the code for your list item renderer too. thanks!

Comment: found a solution! Will post it in a minute...but still thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best solution:

I kept searching and on a site there was lik e method : variableRowHeight but this didn't work in flex 4.5. I searched then again adobe forums and found this threat: adobe forum topic

So it's actually very simple. Just add height in you itemrenderer.

I hope I can help someone with this

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen